# get запрос возвращает все в одну строчку без "\n"

Tags: java, строки, http, post, get

`.getContent()` возвращает все одной строкой. Как это можно исправить. Хочу получить Красивый html код страницы. А получается сплошная строка.

```
public String ExecutePostRequest(String service, Object jsonObject) throws IOException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    Login();

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(baseURL + service);

    PojoUtil gson = null;
    StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(jsonObject), "UTF-8");
    post.setEntity(postingString);


    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

    try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null ) {
            result.append(line);
        }
    } finally {
        response.close();
        httpClient.close();
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Метод [`readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) возвращает строку без завершающего символа `\n`, поэтому надо заменить строчку

```
result.append(line);
```

на что-нибудь вроде

```
result.append(line);
result.append("\n");
```

Comment: Спасибо, странно до этого я делал тоже самое но мне не помогло))) Магия